# Wordpress migration - Admin panel Issues

Tags: wordpress, database-migration

I wanted an exact replica of my current wordpress website on a different domain with a different database.

So I created a database in same db host as the original database.I changed siteurl and homeurl in new database to the corresponding new domain.

I dumped the same code to new IP and changed wp_config file i.e. dbname,dbuser and wp_home wp_siteurl.
I kept db_host same as I have both the databases on same host.

I was able to get the replica up on new domain,but I am facing following issue - 
whenever I change my password for admin in new admin panel , it gets reflected in my original website database and vice a versa.

Similar thing is happening for advanced custom fields in my admin panels.If I change something in new admin panel,it is reflected on my original website.

What could be the issue?? I think I have followed all the guidelines of wordpress migration to other domain.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check that the wp_config.php file is pointing to the correct DB name.

Comment: I checked both the files...It is pointing to correct db name

Comment: I just noticed a very important thing...whenever I log into admin panel of my new website..I get those changes in both the websites...So I guess currently this depends on which admin panel I log into...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the domain name in database then only it will solve the redirection issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated database details in `wp-config.php` file, there is no chance for the issue. First please confirm that both `wp-config.php` files have different database details like database name, user name & password.

For WordPress database migration between different domains, either use `wp-cli` command, or some other database migration plugin. An updating `wp_home` & `wp_siteurl` in DB is not enough.

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/